# Finding element by CSS using Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, css-selectors

I have The following element in my web page:

```
<button id="btnPackageDownloadtopPackageTable1dde0fcb2-948b-4bbc-b347-40deb2f6034e"
 title="Download package" ng-style="{'display': ''}" 
 ng-show="!PackageManagementCtrl.downloadStartedForPackage['topPackageTable1dde0fcb2-948b-4bbc-b347-40deb2f6034e']" 
 phd="{&quot;action&quot;: &quot;enable&quot;, &quot;code&quot;: 3002}"
 phd-unit="Bank(Y)" class="btn action-btn" style="margin-left: 5px;" type="button" 
 ng-click="PackageManagementCtrl.downloadPackage('dde0fcb2-948b-4bbc-b347-40deb2f6034e',
 'Pack_110','topPackageTable1dde0fcb2-948b-4bbc-b347-40deb2f6034e')">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>  Download</button>
```

This is the CSS expression I'm passing to my Selenium code:

[phd-unit='Bank(Y)'][ng-click*='Pack_110'][ng-click*='downloadPackage']

My code:

```
 @Test
public void findElementByCss() {

    softAsserter = new SoftAsserter(testParameters);
    String CssExpresion = testParameters.get("actionData");

    WebElement optionToFind = null;
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 5);
        optionToFind = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(CssExpresion)));
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        softAsserter.fail(ex.getMessage());
    }
    if (optionToFind==null) {
        softAsserter.fail("failed to failed element with expression: " + CssExpresion);
    }
    if (optionToFind!=null) {
        softAsserter.assertTrue(true, "Element found by attributes: </br>" + CssExpresion);
    }
    if (softAsserter.isOneFailed()) {
        asserter.fail("findElementByCss failed");
    }
}
```

Why my code fails in finding this specific element?

Comment: Why do you think it didn't find the element? remove the `try catch` to get the error message. You should also check if it's inside `iframe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was it:

ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated

changed it to:

ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated

And it works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use the following css selector.

```
button.btn.action-btn[title='Download package']
```

OR

```
button.btn.action-btn[title='Download package'][phd-unit='Bank(Y)']
```

Comment: Yes, but there might have very similar elements. I must know that the element has 'Pack_100' and 'Bank(Y)'. Other Elements will have Bank(Z) etc'

Comment: @TalAngel : How about the second one?does that helps.